# Return all duplicates for pandas across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have the following dataframe and would like to return all the duplicate rows

```
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 
| 1 | 4 | 
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
```

I would like the return data to show

```
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
```

I've tried the below, but can't get it working

```
df[df.duplicated(['A','B'], keep='false')]
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `keep='first'`:

```
df[df.duplicated(keep='first')]

   A  B
1  1  2
6  2  3
```